# how to change vertical line color in spyder

Tags: editor, delimiter, spyder

I'm just wondering if the color of the vertical line that works as a wrap delimiter in Spyder's text editor can be changed. If so, can anybody tell me how this is done? Thanks.

Comment: Wrap delimiter? You mean the right margin?

Comment: Yep! That's what I meant :)